# CSS gurus, can I make my absolutely positioned child element force the main parent's height?

Tags: xhtml, css

This is kind of hard to explain.

I have an absolutely positioned floating secondary content box.

It works great in all occurrences.

Except, when you submit a form and don't fill out the fields (see [here](http://www.saltchartersnoosa.com.au/contact), and push *send*). The box expands to show the errors, and underneath the footer there is a blank space. The best example I can give is to see it in action (link above).

I've played with `min-height` and it didn't work too good. I'd also like to avoid expanding the footer with code in the event of form errors if I can help it.

Should I ditch the absolute positioning? And try with margins? Is there any other way to get it to work?

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements cannot float… In your case, I think you mean `#secondary-content`?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel Disable JavaScript probably easiest.

Comment: Bear with me here, but why use 4 lines just for errors? In your position, I would just use one line with a `height` set just high enough to accommodate that error line without distorting anything and just append the different fields to that line, IE `You must enter a name, phone number and inquiry` No?

Comment: @edl I could do that, but then it wouldn't be able to pinpoint individual errors unless I did some string building.

Comment: small price to pay for a beautiful layout. :)

Comment: @eld It wouldn't be too small of a price to pay - I'd need to change quite a few things for that happen. Anyway, I think I have nailed it now.

Comment: Yeah, I already found that solution (to stop the animation). Can you post your own solution? I'm curious…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's the point of absolutes is that they don't affect the parent.

I would suggest not using absolute positioned elements for anything with dynamic content.

In your case i'd try floating the two primary containers to the left, and use a negative top-margin to pull the secondary-content div back up.

There's always js if you dont want to re-code your css but it would be better in the long run to change your css.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I figured I might need to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure how at the moment to get it to *float* (not `float` CSS property) over the bottom content, without absolute positioning, without assuming a height for the content.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066736/css-gurus-can-i-make-my-absolutely-positioned-child-element-force-the-main-paren/3066789#3066789), but I decided to outline the steps I had to take...

First, I changed the inner box to `float: right`, with a `margin: -50px 40px 40px 0;`. This brought the inner box to the correct place up top, but the parent collapsed.

I added an element beneath the `#content` with `clear: left` to make the parent expand to the height of the content on the left.

I then had to absolutely position the elements in the footer, because they were being forced down by the height of the inset box (anyone know a better way to do this?).